# kivy file returning blank screen

Tags: python, error-handling, kivy

Here is the kivy file code:

```
#:kivy 
<MyGridLayout>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Name"
            TextInput:
                multiline:False



            Label:
                text: "Time"
            TextInput:
                multiline:False

            Label:
                text: "Mood"
            TextInput:
                multiline:False

            Button:
                text:"Submit"
```

here is the main file code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
# from numpy import full


class MyGridLayout(Widget):



       def button_pressed(self, instance):
        name = self.name.text
        time = self.time.text
        mood = self.mood.text
        self.add_widget(Label(text=f'hey, {name}\nAccording to your {mood} mood at {time}, we have some suggestions in songs: '))

        self.name.text=""
        self.time.text=""
        self.mood.text=""

class QuizMasters(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__=='__main__':
    QuizMasters().run()
```

Whenever running the file facing the same issue of blank screen, i have saved the main file as QuizMasters.py and the kivy file as QuizMasters.kv , can someone please help...

Comment: Try changing the `kv` file name to all lower case.

Comment: didn't work, in fact it closed immediately when running the kv file with lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified the `kivy` version in `.kv` file. Try setting it like,

```py
#:kivy 2.0.0 # Or replace with your installed version.
.
.
.
```

Comment: sorry to say, but this also didn't worked out
my kivy version was 2.1.0 and i typed it same
#:kivy 2.1.0

Comment: After the required corrections (indentation, specifying version etc.) your posted code ran (in my case) as expected. Make sure you've installed `kivy` properly.

Comment: can you please paste the same code here in the chat @ApuCoder

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, I got an error in the .kv file. Once I deleted the `#:kivy`, it worked out for me.

If that doesn't work, `MyGridLayout` inherits from the `Widget` which makes it a `Widget` that must be added. Try switching into a screen, and tell me if that works.

Also, don't forget, the name of the .kv file must be the same as your `QuizMasters` main class. If your main class includes `app`, you should not include it. In your case, your .kv file should be named `quizmasters.kv` ALL LOWERCASE

Comment: Actually naming the `.kv` file in all lower case and not keeping *app* suffix is a recommendation not a mandatory rule (these are taken care by the `app` class during loading of `.kv` file). In both cases that should work fine.